# QGIS shortcuts for new tasks / for right-click menu?

Tags: qgis, shortcuts

I am looking for a QGIS keyboard shortcut to rename layers (QGIS 3.10.3). I can´t find any in the shortcut-menu.

Therefore two questions:

1. Can I create keyboard shortcuts for new actions that aren´t listed yet in the current shortcut list?
2. Is there a shortcut for "right-click"? I can see when I right-click on the layer that one character in "rename layer" is underscored (in German: "n" in "Layer umbenennen"). Therefore I assume there`s a shortcut possibility, but I can´t find it.

Comment: If you are using Windows, try using F2, it's the sort of universal rename shortcut

Comment: Thanks!! Fn + F2 works!! It is quite a stretch though ;)

Comment: Also I found that I can rightclick, then just put "n" (in German) to get to "rename", that also works better than before.